# how do I get a list of uniq values with at least 2 occurrences?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this active record query:

```
current_user.company.properties.pluck(:name).uniq
```

what I would like to do is get this query but only for properties with 'name' that occur at least twice. how would i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by `name` and add a `having` call as well:

```
...properties.group(:name).having("count(name) > 1").pluck(:name)
```

There's no longer any need for the `uniq` call because, as you're grouping by name, you'll only get each name returned once.